# grant create view using system view with dba privilage in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

When I try to create a view like

```
create view viewname as select * from table1;
```

it is working. But when I try to create view like

```
Create view view1 as Select * from dba_users;
```

I am unable to create it with a exception showing insufficient privileges. However I am able to do a select operation on the given view and getting the results.

```
select * from dba_users;
```

Is there any other role I need to add in order to able to create a view which contains dba_users(or any other tables with dba) as part of its definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is that your access to `dba_users` comes via a role.  If you want to create a view that references `dba_users` (or if you want to creates a definer's rights stored procedure that references `dba_users`), you would need to have privileges granted to your user directly not via a role.  Assuming you want to be able to reference all the data dictionary tables in views and stored procedures, you probably want to ask your DBA to grant you the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege directly not via a role.

Comment: Is it possible to with any other lesser grant as select any dictionary would give me the access to all the data of all the users.

Comment: @DeepakRam - No, it wouldn't.  `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` gives you access to all the data dictionary tables.  The DBA could also grant you access to `dba_users` directly.  It's just that most users that need access to one `dba_*` view end up needing access to many of them so it generally gets annoying to manage those privileges on an object-by-object basis.